# Javascript link to add bbcode to textarea?

Tags: javascript, php

So I created a bbcode parser for my comment section on my website. However I am having trouble figuring out how to have a link fill the following on click to the form textarea. I assuming it would have to been done with javascript which sadly I have not the best at.

```
[quote=user]User's post[quote]
```

Here is the code I have so far for my comment form.

```
<div class="container" id="comment-post-container">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-comments color-icon"></i> Post a comment</h3>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="commentform">
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <form action="/comment.php" method="post">
        <div id="comment_form">
            <textarea cols="40" id="id_body" maxlength="1000" minlength="10" name="message" placeholder="If you ask for translations, you will die." rows="10" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="form-buttom">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="page_id" name="page_id" value="<?= $_GET['id'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="user" name="user" value="<?= $_SESSION['name'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?= $_SESSION['id'] ?>">
    </form>
</div>
```

and to display the comments

```
<div class="container" id="comment-container">
    <div id="comments">
        <?php while ($comment = $comments->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <div class="comment" id="comment-<?= $comment['id'] ?>">
                <a class="avatar" href="/user/<?= $comment['name'] ?>/">
                    <img alt="<?= $comment['avatar'] ?>" src="/uploads/<?= $comment['avatar'] ?>">
                </a>
                <div class="body-wrapper">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="left"><b><a href="/user/<?= $comment['name'] ?>/"><?= $comment['name'] ?></a></b>
                            <a href="/g/<?= $_GET['id'] ?>/#comment-<?= $comment['id'] ?>"><time datetime="<?= $comment['submit_date'] ?>" title="<?= $comment['submit_date'] ?>"><?= time_elapsed_string($comment['submit_date']) ?></time></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <button class="btn btn-unstyled comment-flag">
                                <i class="fa fa-flag"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-unstyled comment-delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body"><?= replaceBBcodes($comment['message']); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <? endwhile ?>
    </div>
</div>
```